# android contentprovider

Tags: android

I’m a beginner to Android development. Something always confuses me. Let say if I want to create a simple app that shows all presidents of United States with some brief info, how do I store this information? Should I store these information in content provider while activity oncreate? Doesn’t it append the data everytime when user start this activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Should I store these information in content provider while activity oncreate?

You never store data in a content provider... a content provider is used in order to (guess what?), provide content. In most cases you won't need to create your own content provider; unless you want to share that data with other apps. If the information you are going to handle is going to be used by your app only, don't create content providers... just put your data in a database and access it from there.

Comment: How do I insert the data to database only from the first time that user start the app?
If I insert the data in activity oncreate, I will inert eveytime when user start the activity.

Comment: Not necessary... you can do that in the onCreate method of the Database helper (**not in the onCreate of the Activity**). It will ensure the data will be stored only once.

Comment: Finally, I decide to prepare a set of database externally with all data ready and just query from directly from app.